# The underlying provider failed on Rollback. Test Performance JMeter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have problem when my method is accessed by more than 10 users at a time.

Here's some example of how I implemented my classes' methods:

```
BeginDbTransaction();

 IdentityResult result = new IdentityResult();
 try
{
    result = await AddAspNetUsers(user, model.Password);
   if (result.Succeeded)
   {
      running method1 //(insert db)
      running method2 //(insert db)
   }
   else{ IsTransRollbacked = true;}

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

The error is "The underlying provider failed on Rollback.".

Anybody can improve my code, please.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not clear but I recommend to rewrite your code something like this :

```
using (var tran=new  BeginDbTransaction())
{
    try
    {
      // open your connection
      // call AddAspNetUsers in order to add new user
     // if you get any error while creating new user throw excetion
     //call another methods
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      tran.RollBack();
    }
}
```

transaction should be created in your `logic layer` not in `UI` layer.
And also new your   `IdentityResult()` in constructor

Comment: Hai Osman, Thans for comment. if i set 'tran' within 'try', catch cannt read 'tran.RollBack();'. cause tran doesnt exist in the current context.

Comment: @Roberts You are right. I updated it/